# Is there a way of removing quotation marks when using the quote crate?

Tags: rust

```rust
use quote::quote; // 1.0.7
use syn; // 1.0.40

fn main() {
    let foo = "foo";
    let foobar = syn::Ident::new(&format!("{}bar", foo), syn::export::Span::call_site());
    let testing = format!("self.{}.is_some()", foobar);
    let q = quote! {#testing};
    println!("{}", q);
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9c9b2c13b2e0d4d3652b9b38c56e652f)

The stdout is

```
"self.foobar.is_some()"
```

I need

```
self.foobar.is_some()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to treat something as a string, don't use a string. Instead, quote the source code directly:

```rust
use quote::{format_ident, quote}; // 1.0.7

fn main() {
    let foo = "foo";
    let foobar = format_ident!("{}bar", foo);
    let q = quote! { self.#foobar.is_some() };
    println!("{}", q);
}
```

```
self . foobar . is_some ()
```

If your data **has** to be a string (e.g. you read it from a configuration file), then you can use syn to [parse](https://docs.rs/syn/1.0.41/syn/parse/index.html) the string back into the AST and the apply the above solution. This does require that you need to know *what* to parse the string as.

In this case, we want to parse the whole string as an *expression*:

```rust
use quote::quote; // 1.0.7
use syn; // 1.0.40

fn main() {
    let foobar = "self.foobar.is_some()";

    let e: syn::Expr = syn::parse_str(foobar).expect("Unable to parse");
    let q = quote! { #e };
    
    println!("{}", q);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, for some reason I thought the printed spaces in between the tokens were a problem, but I guess that only exists when you print them out.

Another related question, is I have `EnumVarient::Something` that isn't a ident, what do I use to remove the `" "` in that case (since I can't use `format_ident!()`?

Comment: @0x42 Where do you need to remove space from? `EnumVariant :: Something` is valid Rust code. If you want it nicely formatted for reading you should run it through `rustfmt` (but generated code is rarely if ever going to be beautiful, anyway).

Comment: @0x42 That all depends on how you “have it”. if you have the type name and the variant name as separate variables then quote them individually.

Comment: The type name and the variant name are in the same string

Comment: @0x42 why not structure your data differently so they aren’t?

Comment: True, I was able to use syn::parse_str::<Expr>(&s) anyway. thanks.